# Dispatch semaphores and memory visibility

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, thread-safety, semaphore

If I signal a dispatch semaphore in one thread and wait for it in another thread, is the waiting thread guaranteed to see all changes made by the signalling thread upto a point? If so, is it synchronized at the signalling point or the waiting point?